# アプリ起動時「func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation」が呼ばれません。

Tags: swift

アプリ起動時にViewControllerを強制的に縦画面で表示したいのですが、

```
func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
    return .Portrait
}
```

が呼ばれません。

SingleViewアプリケーションで以下のようにサンプルを作ってもよばれません。

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation() -> UIInterfaceOrientation {
        return .Portrait
    }


    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .All
    }

}
```

呼ばれるようにするにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

それぞれの関数に `print(__FUNCTION__)` でも挿入していただければわかると思いますが、どの関数も正常に呼ばれています。
（Xcode 7.2 / シミュレーター環境で確認）

アプリを強制的に縦画面で表示する方法ですが、コードから実現する場合、以下のコードだけで実現できるかと思われます。

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return .Portrait
    }
}
```

もっと単純に、[Targets] - [Deployment Info]からDevice Orientationを指定する方法もあります。

[image: デバイスの向きを指定]

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。起動時は強制的にPortraitとし、起動後は、Landscapeもサポートしたいです。

Comment: 起動前／起動後のフラグをコードから管理するようにして、そのフラグに応じて、supportedInterfaceOrientations()で返す値を変化させれば良いかと思われます。

Comment: viewControllerのsupportedInterfaceOrientations()でフラグを使ってやっていたのですが、起動前に横画面になってから縦になるようでうまくいきませんでした。「appDelegateのfunc application(application: UIApplication,
        supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask」で指定することではじめから縦で起動できました！回答として載せました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 0):

```
 class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

        //...

            func application(application: UIApplication,
                    supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow window: UIWindow?) -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
                        if allowsLandscape == false {
                            return .Portrait
                        } else {
                            return .All
                        }
            }
}
```

viewControllerから特定のタイミングで、`allowsLandscape`フラグを変更することで、できました。